# Download Multiple Images with Curl

Tags: php, curl

How to downolad images from multiples urls, now it works only with one url.
I think it should be array but cant make it work even with that.

```
<?php 

$url_to_image = 'https://images.somesite.1.jpg', 'https://images.somesite.2.jpg';

$ch = curl_init($url_to_image);

$my_save_dir = 'images/';
$filename = basename($url_to_image);
$complete_save_loc = $my_save_dir . $filename;

$fp = fopen($complete_save_loc, 'wb');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Can only download with one url, but i have 10 urls to be download in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello,

You found the answer by yourself.

You must as you said put the images in an array and loop on it.

```
$urls = ['https://images.somesite.1.jpg', 'https://images.somesite.2.jpg'];

$my_save_dir = 'images/';
foreach ($urls as $url) {
   $ch = curl_init($url_to_image);
   $filename = basename($url);
   $complete_save_loc = $my_save_dir . $filename;

   $fp = fopen($complete_save_loc, 'wb');

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: hi, Thank you Eclairia, just changed curl_init($url_to_image) to curl_init($url) and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through an array. $url_to_image isn't an array in your code snippet

```
$url_to_image = ['https://images.somesite.1.jpg', 'https://images.somesite.2.jpg'];
$my_save_dir = 'images/';

foreach ($url_to_image as $url) {
$ch = curl_init($url);
$filename = basename($url);
$complete_save_loc = $my_save_dir . $filename;
$fp = fopen($complete_save_loc, 'wb');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
}
```